# Cortex rules: formatting on action rolls

Tags: cortex

If you are writing down a roll, what is the accepted format for action rolls? 
For example, if your Agility is d12+d4 and your Pistol is d12+d2, and you spend 3 plot points, it's Agility+Pistol. But how would you write that roll down?

Is it:

```
     d12+d4+d12+d2+d6
```

or:

```
     2d12+d6+d4+d2
```

or:

```
     [d12+d4]+[d12+d2]+d6
```

or (to distinguish plot points):

```
     [d12+d4]+[d12+d2]+[d6 PP]
```

This is using the basic Cortex rules. Thanks.

Comment: I think its sort of contextual. As a gm I would write `[d12+d4]+[d12+d2]+[d6 PP]` but when writing to a player it would be `2d12+d6+d4+d2`. As a GM break it down so if I decide to tweak something I can quickly BS my way through my completely arbitrary decision to make it harder/easier.

Comment: Makes sense. Context: I'm writing a program to handle combat in the Cortex game (keeping track of damage, actions, dodges, etc.), and part of that is including a way to display rolls.

Comment: @Chad - I think your comment constitutes an answer. If you make it into an answer, I'll upvote it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think its sort of contextual. As a gm I would write `[d12+d4]+[d12+d2]+[d6 PP]` but when writing to a player it would be `2d12+d6+d4+d2`. As a GM break it down so if I decide to tweak something I can quickly BS my way through my completely arbitrary decision to make it harder/easier.

As for your program It probably depends what you want to do.  I would probably provide the data the second option with perhaps some way to see what was used to come up with that roll and denote it in your 4th way.